# Powershell excel to csv script works in ISE but not in powershell console

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a short script that takes certain worksheets out of an excel file and saves them individually as a CSV file.

```
Function ExcelToCsv ($File) {
    $myDir = Split-Path -Parent $($global:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)
    $path = "$myDir\csv_files"
    If(!(test-path -PathType container $path))
    {
        Write-Host "Folder csv_files not found, creating..."
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $path
    }
    $excelFile = "$myDir\" + $File + ".xlsx"
    $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $wb = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($excelFile)
    $excel.DisplayAlerts = $false;
    
    foreach ($ws in $wb.Worksheets) {
        if($ws.name -like '*sheet*') {
            $ws.SaveAs("$myDir\csv_files\" + $ws.name + ".csv", 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, $true)
            Write-Host "Saved file: $myDir\csv_files\"$ws.name".csv"
        } else {
            Write-Host "Worksheet "$ws.name" not an correct sheet. Not saved"
        }
    }
    $Excel.Quit()
}

$FileName = "myexcel"
ExcelToCsv -File $FileName
Write-Host "`nCSV files successfully created"
read-host "Press ENTER to exit...."
```

This is the entire code, not much to it and this is the correct output when run from ISE:

```
PS U:\excel_to_csv> U:\excel_to_csv\create_csv_files.ps1
Saved file: U:\excel_to_csv\csv_files\ 1sheet .csv
Saved file: U:\excel_to_csv\csv_files\ 2sheet .csv
Saved file: U:\excel_to_csv\csv_files\ 3sheet .csv

CSV files successfully created
Press ENTER to exit....:
```

But when I use a Powershell console:

```
Folder csv_files not found, creating...
New-Item : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'if((Get-ExecutionPolicy ) -ne 'AllSigned') { Set-ExecutionPolicy -
Scope Process Bypass }; & 'U' does not exist.
At U:\excel_to_csv\create_csv_files.ps1:7 char:9
+         New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $path
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (if((Get-Executi... Bypass }; & 'U:String) [New-Item], DriveNotFoundExce
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand

Ľutujeme, if((Get-ExecutionPolicy ) -ne 'AllSigned') { Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process Bypass }; & 'U:\excel_to_csv\
myexcel.xlsx sa nepodarilo nájsť. Je možné, že bol premiestnený, premenovaný alebo odstránený.
At U:\excel_to_csv\create_csv_files.ps1:11 char:5
+     $wb = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($excelFile)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException


CSV files successfully created
Press ENTER to exit....:
```

Some of it is written in Slovakian, it roughly translates to:

```
Sorry, if((Get-ExecutionPolicy ) -ne 'AllSigned') { Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process Bypass }; & 'U:\excel_to_csv\
    myexcel.xlsx could not be found. It is possible it was moved, renamed or deleted.
```

I have tried searching for a solution but nothing worked yet.
I tried making a bash script like this:

powershell.exe -noexit -file U:\create_csv_files.ps1

But that didn't work, not sure if I screwed it up.

As I am on a company computer I am unable to use administrator privileges, but if you believe the lack of them is the problem, I might be able to do something about it.

Thank you for any and all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
$myDir = Split-Path -Parent $($global:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)
```

with

```
$myDir = $PSScriptRoot
```

The automatic **[`$PSScriptRoot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#psscriptroot)** variable *reliably* reports the **full path of the *directory* in which the currently executing script is located**, irrespective of how the script was invoked. The related **[`$PSCommandPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#pscommandpath)** variable contains the ***script file's* own full path**.

---

Your symptom implies that you invoked your script from outside a PowerShell session, via `powershell.exe -Command` (with the `-Command` [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) parameter potentially being positionally implied), in which case `$global:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition` contains the *entire command text* passed to `-Command`.

Comment: Oh my, such a simple change, that was actually one of the worst parts of this script to figure out. I had to try at least 3 variants of Split-Path -Parent to make it work at all. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @Laggger164.